# Executing PHP inside another PHP

Tags: php

I have following 2 php pages which is actually containing html tags (in 2nd page only) with out php tag start and end.

**page1.php**

```
<div>Page 1</div>
<?php exec('/usr/bin/php page2.php');
?>
```

**page2.php in same directory**

```
<div> this is page 2</div>
```

**Actual result** : 2nd page is not printed when page1.php is executed

**Expected result**: both page 1 and page 2 php result should come in page1.php when hit from broswer.. in this case , following is the expected result..

```
Page 1
this is page 2
```

Note : This is just an example. my page is containing 1000s of lines in page2.php

Comment: Can I ask _why_ you would do this? Why not `include('page2.php')`?

Comment: include or require is not working...

Comment: @logan Mind specifying "not working"?

Comment: If it isn't working, please post any error messages you receive.  If you don't see any, turn on `display_errors`. Always during development:  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: i tried error_reporting(E_ALL); nothing is displayed. none of the text from page2.php is getting printed

Comment: You also need `display_errors`, if something is faulty (like the file not existing in the expected path).  Look at the browser page source when calling the include. Is it being rendered, but broken in HTML if the markup is bad? This is one of the exact purposes of `include()/require()` and it will work correctly if done and debugged correctly.

Comment: there is a problem with my path to page2.php. i have corrected it . it works now. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [require](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) or [include](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) (or in particular, probably [require_once](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php))

i.e.

```
<div>Page 1</div>
<?php 
    require("page2.php");
?>
```

Unless you're trying to do something far stranger than i've anticipated.

Comment: there is a problem with my path to page2.php. i have corrected it . it works now. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Per the docs, `exec` only **returns** (i.e. you'd have to echo it) the **last** line of the output. `passthru` or `system` would work better, but you really should be using `include` or `require` instead.

Comment: I find that unlikely.

Comment: there is a problem with my path to page2.php. i have corrected it . it works now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the following on **page1.php**:

```
<div>Page 1</div>
<?php 
include ("page2.php");
?>
```

Hope that works for you... :)

Answer (score 0):

**You can use it multiple time in a php file**
`<div>Page</div>
<?php
include once "page2.php";
or
require once "page2.php";
?>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$data['id_rm']?>">
<label for="pasien">Nama Pasien</label>
<select name="pasien" id="pasien" class="form-control" required>
    <option value="<?=$data['id_pasien']?>" selected="selected"><?=$data['nama_pasien']?></option>
    <option value="">- Pilih Pasien -</option>
    <?php 
        $sql_pasien = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM tb_pasien") or die(mysqli_error($con));
        while($data_pasien = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_pasien)) {
            echo '<option value="'.$data_pasien['id_pasien'].'">'.$data_pasien['nama_pasien'].'</option>';
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Probably an explanation would be helpful as well.